# Override the Style of Form templates in Django

Tags: python, css, django, forms

I am new to django, I am building a form on django  and found the built in forms django and implement this.

From the django documentation, it says that  `form.subject` will put a `<input type="text">` in it. But what if i want to change the properties of this input element such as height, font, text, width etc. how would do this.

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.subject.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.subject.id_for_label }}">Email subject:</label>
    {{ form.subject }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.message.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.message.id_for_label }}">Your message:</label>
    {{ form.message }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.sender.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.sender.id_for_label }}">Your email address:</label>
    {{ form.sender }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.cc_myself.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.cc_myself.id_for_label }}">CC yourself?</label>
    {{ form.cc_myself }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery for this.

each django form element has its unique id. use that id for applying the css properties using jquery.

access form element using id.

```
$('#id_subject').addClass('form-group'); #  formgroup is a bootstrap class.
 or 
$('#id_subject').css('height', '10px');
```

apply any css property you want here.
this properties should get applied once the page is loaded i.e.
on document.ready in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances) you can add css classes:

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'special'}))
```

Assuming you are familiar with css, you can apply styles to that field now.

There is a way to style all the widgets, but it requires better knowledge about python and django in general.

Another alternative is to use some django app that allows this, like [crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [floppy-forms](https://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)